# Uncaught TypeError: pushRoom.on is not a function which I console.log it but don't know how to solve it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My source main code is

```
import { useCookies } from "react-cookie";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import axios from "axios";
import {  getDownloadURL, getStorage } from "firebase/storage";
import { ref, getDatabase, child } from "firebase/database";
import Map from "./Map";
import ModalWindow from "../NewFeedComponents/Modal";
import AnnouncementMessage from "../NewFeedComponents/Announcement";
import "./listUsers.css";
import NavbarListPage from "../NewFeedComponents/NavbarNewFeed";
import Loader from "../NewFeedComponents/loader/Loader";
import Loader2 from "../NewFeedComponents/loader/loader2";

/**
 * @param {*} props
 */

function ListUsers() {
  const [cookies] = useCookies(["userName"]);
  const [radius, setRadius] = useState("");
  const [list, setList] = useState({
    success: false,
    err: "",
  });

  const [isColorBtn, setColorBtn] = useState("FindMe");
  const [isShowLoader, setIsShowLoader] = useState(false);
  const [isShowMap, setShowMap] = useState(false);
  const [user, setUser] = useState("");
  const [url, setUrl] = useState("");
  const [loader, setLoader] = useState();
  const database = ref(getDatabase());
  const pushRoom = child(database, `${cookies.userName}`);
  useEffect(() => {
    const loader = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    setLoader(loader);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleNewMessages = async (snap) => {
      if (snap.val()) {
        Object.entries(snap.val()).forEach((el) => {
          const [, obj] = el;
          obj && setUser(obj);
        });
        pushRoom.remove();
      }
    };
    console.log(pushRoom);
    pushRoom.on("value", handleNewMessages);
    return () => {
      pushRoom.off("value", handleNewMessages);
    };
  });
```

After I console.log(pushRoom) it shows **undefined** but when I console.log(pushRoom.on) it shows

```
_orderByCalled: false
_path: Path {pieces_: Array(1), pieceNum_: 0}
_queryParams: QueryParams {limitSet_: false, startSet_: false, startNameSet_: false, startAfterSet_: false, endSet_: false, …}
_repo: Repo {repoInfo_: RepoInfo, forceRestClient_: false, authTokenProvider_: FirebaseAuthTokenProvider, appCheckProvider_: AppCheckTokenProvider, dataUpdateCount: 0, …}
key: (...)
parent: (...)
ref: (...)
root: (...)
_queryIdentifier: (...)
_queryObject: (...)
[[Prototype]]: QueryImpl
```

When I setup my profile in process page that I finally click submit for linked to user page then it shows nothing with white page entirely that's why I check console --> see error --> check with console.log like I said above. Very appreciated for helping!

Answer (score 0):

You're importing v9 or later of the SDK, which have switched from a namespaced API (`pushRoom.on("value", ...`) to a modular API (`onValue(pushRoom, ...`. You'll also need to import the `onValue` function, just as you do with `getDatabase` and others.

So something like:

```
import { ref, getDatabase, child, onValue } from "firebase/database";
...
const unsubscribe = onValue(pushRoom, handleNewMessages);
return () => unsubscribe();
```

I recommend keeping the Firebase documentation handy, and using the side-by-side v8 and v9 [snippets](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#web-version-9_2) to ease the rewrite, and reading the [upgrade guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade).

Comment: Very very very appreciated sincerely sir.